# Use a COM object in compatibility mode?

Tags: com, windows-8, compatibility

I have a 3rd party COM component that won't work on Windows 8 but will work perfectly fine if run in Windows 7 compatibility mode on Windows 8. However, I don't want the software to run in compatibility mode, just the COM component. Is it possible?

BTW, it's not possible to get a newer/working version of the COM component.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Compatibility mode applies to a whole process at a time. The only way to do what you ask for is to run the COM object in a different container process, either using DCOM (if the COM object's interfaces have the necessary stubs and proxies registered for use as an out-of-process object) or by writing your own remoting layer.